# Hover effect on SVG

Tags: html, css

I have SVG of US map with 5 different regions created with `g` element. I want to change the color of the region on hover of the region but i can not get the result on hover.

When i apply hover effect on `region-hover` class by inspecting an element then it is working perfectly.

I require hover effect on all the `path` element inside the `g` element having class `region-hover`.

Find my code below and suggest me if anything wrong.

Here is my code:

https://codepen.io/jaydipshingala/pen/qYBRwZ

Comment: You want hover effect on diff regions

Comment: Yes, I want hover effect on different regions

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `g path {pointer-events: none}` it's preventing the hover:

> The element is **never** the target of mouse events;<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)</sup>

```
.region-hover:hover .state-hover {
  stroke: #d45422 !important;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: #d45422 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}


svg {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/37tvx5bu/

Answer (score 1):

you have add `point-event: none` to `g path`, that why `:hover` effect not working